# cakephp3 validation function according to a field in the same form

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

Hey guys i need help in a cakephp 3 model

i am trying to validate the data from a form. what i am trying to do is to check the value against a pattern but i need the validation function to check the type and accordingly choosing the pattern to compare with

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->add('name', [
            'notBlank' => [
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => (__('Name should not be empty'))
            ],
            'maxlength' => [
                'rule' => ['maxLength', 100],
                'message' => (__('Name should be at most 100 characters long'))
            ]
        ])
        ->add('type', [
            'inList' => [
                'rule' => ['inList', ['hotLine', 'phoneNumber']],
                'message' => (__('The type must be available in the types list'))
            ]
        ])
        ->add('value', [
            'checkType' => [
                'rule' => function ($value, $context) {

                },
                'message' => (__('The value does not match the type you chose'))
            ]
        ]);
}
```

the rule function should check the data if it is valid according to the type chosen in the field above (hotLine or phoneNumber)

your help is highly appreciated

btw if i am doing something wrong please point it out

thanks in advance

Comment: And your actual problem is _what_?

Comment: how can i access the type from the function and use it to validate the data provided?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules "Closures or callable methods will receive 2 arguments when called. The first will be the value for the field being validated. The second is a context array containing data related to the validation process"

Comment: Thanks Sevvlor. it did the trick